# temporary table vs temporary table variable indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a temp table in a stored procedure and indexed it as well as create a temp variable table and indexed it. I find the temp table faster. Please see my implementation below. Could somebody tell me if there is any difference between the way i have applied indexes

**temp table implementation**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#maxPeriod') is not null drop table #maxPeriod  else
    select 
            fp.companyId,
            max(fi.periodenddate) as maxPeriod
    into #maxPeriod
    from ciqfinperiod fp inner join ciqcompany ci on fp.companyId = ci.companyId
            join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
    where fp.periodtypeid = 4
            and fi.periodenddate > @date
            and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 

    group by fp.companyId

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_companyId2 on #maxPeriod(companyId,maxPeriod)
```

**temporary table variable implementation**

```
DECLARE @maxPeriod TABLE (companyId INT, maxPeriod smalldatetime,
                          UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED  (companyId, maxPeriod))
    INSERT INTO @maxPeriod  
select 
        fp.companyId,
        max(fi.periodenddate) as maxPeriod

from ciqfinperiod fp inner join ciqcompany ci on fp.companyId = ci.companyId
        join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
where fp.periodtypeid = 4
        and fi.periodenddate > @date
        and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
        and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 

group by fp.companyId
```

Comment: The latter has a UNIQUE constraint the former does not ..

Comment: how do i apply non clustered index only to temporary table variables

Comment: I am finding the former faster than the latter currently

Comment: I don't think the index on the temporary table variable do anything.

Comment: Temp tables have statistics. Table variables don't. This can cause different execution plans. You can try adding `option (recompile)` to the statements using the table variable one. This can take into account cardinality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temp tables are generally faster, see the following link for a clear explanation: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/temp-tables-table-variables-memory-optimized-table-variables/